# How to convert an HTTP-date into a delay in milliseconds

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timezone

I am making a Node.js service which needs to make HTTP GET requests and retry them when they encounter a 503 response.

From the W3.org's [Header Field Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.37):

> The Retry-After response-header field can be used with a 503 (Service
>   Unavailable) response to indicate how long the service is expected to
>   be unavailable to the requesting client. [...] The value of this field
>   can be either an HTTP-date or an integer number of seconds (in
>   decimal) after the time of the response. [...] Two examples of its use
>   are
>
> ```
>    Retry-After: Fri, 31 Dec 1999 23:59:59 GMT
>    Retry-After: 120
> ```

I want to use this information to trigger a retry at the appropriate time. This is easy with seconds, because I can easily transform them into milliseconds and `setTimeout(fn, ms)`. The HTTP-date version is much harder. I need to find my server's timezone, transform the provided date into that timezone, subtract the current time from the provided time, convert the result to milliseconds, and then `setTimeout(fn, ms)` if `ms` is positive.

I can do all this, of course, but I would expect a library to exist already which does this as this seems like a fairly common thing to do. However, I can't seem to find one. Any leads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
var d = new Date("Tue, 19 Aug 2014 13:50:59 GMT"); // d is in your timezone now
d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds()+120);
var diff = d.getTime()-Date.now();
if (diff>0) var tId=setTimeout(something,diff);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/LyLszvhv/)

Comment: Easy enough. I didn't know Date automatically converted to local timezone.